# Restore SQLBASE 7.0 .dbs

Tags: database, restore, sqlbase

I am trying to restore a .dbs file. I know its version is 7.0.1 and can not restore in sqlbase 12. I just need to recover the data.

I already tried to open in word, gedit, libre office calc, suggestions seen on the internet. But I can not retrieve this data.

I tried searching sqlBase 7 but I also did not find it.
Anyone know of a solution to this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see you are using SQLBase 12.  However - you don't use 'Restore' , you must UNLOAD and then RELOAD the schema and data. Very easy .
Use SQLTalk to do the whole thing. It is 'sqltalk.exe' found in the SQLBase run-time folder. Here is the syntax for UNLOAD: ( Use UNLOAD DATABASE to unload the entire Schema plus Data )
[image]

Once UNLOADED to a file, here is the syntax for LOAD .
[image]

Here is a link to the online SQLBase User Guide:

[SQLBase online User Guide](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/SQLBase_12_Documentation)

Comment: Your instructions worked perfectly to .sql file, but i don't have the SQLBase 7.0.1 to run the unload command, i just have the .dbs file. Do you know how to get this old version of SQLBase?